# pdfjs with magento 2

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2, pdf.js

I could integrate pdfjs with magento 2 requireJS.
have downloaded files from here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdf.js and placed them in my_theme/web/js/ folder

added pdfjs to requirejs script:

my_theme/web/js/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf': 'js/pdf.min',
        'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker': 'js/pdf.worker.min'
    }
};
```

add script to page :

```
require(["js/pdf", "js/pdf.worker"],function(pdfjsLib, pdfWorker){
  //define url other parts of script..
  pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    // Initial/first page rendering
    renderPage(pageNum);
  });
});
```

script is loaded i can see that both pdf.min.js and pdf.worker.min.js where loaded with magento.

but still getting following error: Cannot read property 'getDocument' of undefined.
from test both variables are undefined: pdfjsLib, pdfWorker

any idea what is wrong here ?

if we use :
`require(["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf", "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker"],function(pdfjsLib, pdfWorker){`

we get 404 since it will try to load script from website/pub/static/vendor/theme/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.min.js

but file is located at website/pub/static/vendor/theme/js/pdf.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have Magento2 setup but I did a simple HTML setup and it is working:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var config = {
        paths: {
            'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.min',
            'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.worker.min'
        }
    };
    requirejs.config(config);
    require(["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf", "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker"],function(pdfjsLib, pdfWorker){
        console.log(pdfjsLib, pdfWorker);
    });
</script>
```

Maybe this will help you :)